# Is "for a soon-clear reason" a correct phrasing?

Tags: phrase-request, phrase-choice

I a part of my paper I am going to call this thing I am talking about "XYZ". The reason why I call it XYZ would be clear very soon in the paper. So can I say the following?

> **For a soon-clear reason**, I call this XYZ.

Or "for a soon-obvious reason"? Or there are other way of phrasing for that purpose.

Comment: I'd recommend "soon-to-be-made-clear" or "soon-to-be-obvious", or non-hyphenated versions like "For a reason soon to be made clear" and "for a reason which will soon be obvious"

Comment: @Hellion Can I just say "for what will soon be obvious,"?

Comment: Sasan: You definitely *can* say that!  In fact, it's probably the best choice for a learner, since things get much more complicated when you have to try and find out what makes @Hellion's suggestion "correct". Some "ad-hoc, one-off" hyphenated leading adjectives work, and some don't (and some don't *always* include hyphens in the written form), but it's very easy to get things wrong in this area if you're not a native speaker.

Comment: Note that there is nothing actually ***incorrect*** with *soon-clear reason*. The alternatives are merely being given as more common (and natural).